# Is this going to work when trying to delete more users from AzureADGroup?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

My Script is currently like this:

```
$azureAdGroupWeAreCurrentlyWorkingWith = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString 'name of the group'
$azureAdGroupWeAreCurrentlyWorkingWith | Get-AzureADGroupMember | Select-Object * | Where-Object {$_.UserType -ne 'Member'} | Remove-AzureADGroupMember
```

#### Question Explained

I want to delete users from `AzureADGroup` and avoid writing `for` or `foreach`.

Comment: Shouldn't `Where-Object {$_.UserType -ne 'Member'}` be `Where-Object {$_.ObjectType -eq 'User'}` ? And I think you can safely remove `Select-Object *`

Comment: Look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0#example-1--get-a-group-member-by-id). Clearly there is an attribute `ObjectType` that can have value `User`..

Comment: Absolutely not ` Where-Object {$_.UserType -ne 'Member'}  be Where-Object {$_.ObjectType -eq 'User'}`, because Azure Active Directory in this case has two types Guest or Member, if you are not one of them then you doesn't exist as an user in AzureAD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$azureAdGroupWeAreCurrentlyWorkingWith = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString 'name of the group'

$users =($azureAdGroupWeAreCurrentlyWorkingWith | Get-AzureADGroupMember |Select-Object *|  Where-Object {$_.UserType -ne 'Member'}) 

$users | select-object -property @{N='MemberId';E={$_.ObjectId }},@{N='ObjectId';E={$azureAdGroupWeAreCurrentlyWorkingWith.ObjectId }}  | Remove-AzureADGroupMember
```

Comment: yes, it helped, but there is no way it could work as I write in my question due to ObjectId, yes ?

Comment: @MOFG Yes. Your script doesn't work because `Remove-AzureADGroupMember` cannot get the Group id (object id).